# SQL Query To Trim the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I have a query as follows

```
select 
    First_Name+' '+Middle_Name+' '+Last_Name as studentname,
    Batch,
    Batch+1 as batch1,
    Admtd_Semester,
    Program,
    Title,
    @His_Her as His_Her,
    Fathers_Name,
    Branch_Name,
    Student_Mobile_Number,
    Fathers_Mobilenumber,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) as date 
from 
    STUDENT_Admission_1212341
```

In the above query, batch+1 gives the output as 2014 in which I need only 14. How can I trim it?

Comment: Plz specify what's the data type of `Batch` and what are possible set of values in this column?

Comment: @Deepshikha the data type will be `int`. He added `+1` right?

Answer (score 4):

Calc the remainder:

```
SELECT 2014 % 100
```

I.e.:

```
SELECT  First_Name + ' ' + Middle_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS studentname ,
        Batch ,
        (Batch + 1 ) % 100 AS batch1 ,
        Admtd_Semester ,
        Program ,
        Title ,
        @His_Her AS His_Her ,
        Fathers_Name ,
        Branch_Name ,
        Student_Mobile_Number ,
        Fathers_Mobilenumber ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS date
FROM    STUDENT_Admission_1212341
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RIGHT(CAST(Batch + 1 AS VARCHAR(10), 2) AS batch1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    First_Name+' '+Middle_Name+' '+Last_Name as studentname,
    Batch,
    RIGHT(Batch + 1, 2) as batch1,
    Admtd_Semester,
    Program,
    Title,
    @His_Her as His_Her,
    Fathers_Name,
    Branch_Name,
    Student_Mobile_Number,
    Fathers_Mobilenumber,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) as date 
from 
    STUDENT_Admission_1212341
```

**Tests**

2099 gives 99

2009 gives 09

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you try using **SubString**

```
select 
    First_Name+' '+Middle_Name+' '+Last_Name as studentname,
    Batch,
  substring(Batch+1,3,4) as batch1,
    Admtd_Semester,
    Program,
    Title,
    @His_Her as His_Her,
    Fathers_Name,
    Branch_Name,
    Student_Mobile_Number,
    Fathers_Mobilenumber,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) as date 
from 
    STUDENT_Admission_1212341
```

This will probably give you the same result

Comment: i tried using substring but it did not worked as the batch+1 is not the actual field present in table it is 1 added to batch

Comment: Either of these can help you out. You need to substring as **Select SUBSTRING('2013'+1,3,4)** or
**Select SUBSTRING('2013',3,4)+1**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT First_Name + ' ' + Middle_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS studentname
      ,Batch
      ,right(Batch,2) + 1 AS batch1
      ,Admtd_Semester
      ,Program
      ,Title
      ,@His_Her AS His_Her
      ,Fathers_Name
      ,Branch_Name
      ,Student_Mobile_Number
      ,Fathers_Mobilenumber
      ,CONVERT ( VARCHAR ( 10 ) ,GETDATE () ,110 ) AS date
FROM STUDENT_Admission_1212341;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RIGHT` function.

```
SELECT First_Name+' '+Middle_Name+' '+Last_Name AS studentname, 
Batch, 
RIGHT(Batch,2) + 1 AS batch1, 
Admtd_Semester, 
Program,Title, 
@His_Her AS His_Her, 
Fathers_Name, 
Branch_Name, 
Student_Mobile_Number, 
Fathers_Mobilenumber, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) AS date 
FROM STUDENT_Admission_1212341
```